# How to use NGINX with templating?

Tags: nginx, html, template

Is there any way to do templating in nginx? For example, if I have a file like this:

```
{header}
<h1>This is a header</h1>
This is not a header
{footer}
```

and then use NGINX to replace `{header}` with, say, this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>This is a title</title></head>
<body>
```

and `{footer}` with a similar thing. The purpose of this would be to be able to have shared code between html files. Is this possible in nginx, or will I have to use a reverse proxy to a different server program that can do templating?

Comment: nginx is a web server, not a template engine.

Comment: Use PHP, which Nginx can call.

Comment: You could try SSI, but it would be much better to use PHP/Python/whatever…

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that with nginx you will have to find a different way to do it.

Comment: Actually, there is good old `ssi` directive.